# How to draw a path on a map using kml file?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, kml

Can I parse kml file in order to display paths or points in Android? Please could you help me with that?

This is kml sample code which I would like to display in android google map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>Paths</name>
<description>Examples of paths. Note that the tessellate tag is by default
  set to 0. If you want to create tessellated lines, they must be authored
  (or edited) directly in KML.</description>
<Style id="yellowLineGreenPoly">
  <LineStyle>
    <color>7f00ffff</color>
    <width>4</width>
  </LineStyle>
  <PolyStyle>
    <color>7f00ff00</color>
  </PolyStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
  <name>Absolute Extruded</name>
  <description>Transparent green wall with yellow outlines</description>
  <styleUrl>#yellowLineGreenPoly</styleUrl>
  <LineString>
    <extrude>1</extrude>
    <tessellate>1</tessellate>
    <altitudeMode>absolute</altitudeMode>
    <coordinates> -112.2550785337791,36.07954952145647,2357
      -112.2549277039738,36.08117083492122,2357
      -112.2552505069063,36.08260761307279,2357
      -112.2564540158376,36.08395660588506,2357
      -112.2580238976449,36.08511401044813,2357
      -112.2595218489022,36.08584355239394,2357
      -112.2608216347552,36.08612634548589,2357
      -112.262073428656,36.08626019085147,2357
      -112.2633204928495,36.08621519860091,2357
      -112.2644963846444,36.08627897945274,2357
      -112.2656969554589,36.08649599090644,2357 
    </coordinates>
    <LineString>
    </Placemark>
    </Document>
    </kml>
```

When I'm loading this file to standard web google map it displays it nicely but when I'm trying the same thing with android google map it doesn't do that. It just takes me to some locations and that's it. I was thinking of changing listener class. Currently it looks like that:

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        if (loc != null) {
            latitude = (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6);
            longitude = (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6);
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                     "Location changed : Lat: " + latitude + 
                     " Lng: " + longitude, 
                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint(
                     (int) (loc.getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                     (int) (loc.getLongitude() * 1E6));

             mc.animateTo(p);
             mapView.invalidate();
           }
    }

//---------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
        Bundle extras) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Please can someone tell me what's I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

In above code, you don't pass the kml data to your mapView anywhere in your code, as far as I can see.
To display the route, you should parse the kml data i.e. via SAX parser, then display the route markers on the map.

See the code below for an example, but it's not complete though - just for you as a reference and get some idea.

This is a simple bean I use to hold the route information I will be parsing.

```
package com.myapp.android.model.navigation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class NavigationDataSet { 

private ArrayList<Placemark> placemarks = new ArrayList<Placemark>();
private Placemark currentPlacemark;
private Placemark routePlacemark;

public String toString() {
    String s= "";
    for (Iterator<Placemark> iter=placemarks.iterator();iter.hasNext();) {
        Placemark p = (Placemark)iter.next();
        s += p.getTitle() + "\n" + p.getDescription() + "\n\n";
    }
    return s;
}

public void addCurrentPlacemark() {
    placemarks.add(currentPlacemark);
}

public ArrayList<Placemark> getPlacemarks() {
    return placemarks;
}

public void setPlacemarks(ArrayList<Placemark> placemarks) {
    this.placemarks = placemarks;
}

public Placemark getCurrentPlacemark() {
    return currentPlacemark;
}

public void setCurrentPlacemark(Placemark currentPlacemark) {
    this.currentPlacemark = currentPlacemark;
}

public Placemark getRoutePlacemark() {
    return routePlacemark;
}

public void setRoutePlacemark(Placemark routePlacemark) {
    this.routePlacemark = routePlacemark;
}

}
```

And the SAX Handler to parse the kml:

```
package com.myapp.android.model.navigation;

import android.util.Log;
import com.myapp.android.myapp;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import com.myapp.android.model.navigation.NavigationDataSet;
import com.myapp.android.model.navigation.Placemark;


public class NavigationSaxHandler extends DefaultHandler{ 

 // =========================================================== 
 // Fields 
 // =========================================================== 

 private boolean in_kmltag = false; 
 private boolean in_placemarktag = false; 
 private boolean in_nametag = false;
 private boolean in_descriptiontag = false;
 private boolean in_geometrycollectiontag = false;
 private boolean in_linestringtag = false;
 private boolean in_pointtag = false;
 private boolean in_coordinatestag = false;

 private StringBuffer buffer;

 private NavigationDataSet navigationDataSet = new NavigationDataSet(); 

 // =========================================================== 
 // Getter & Setter 
 // =========================================================== 

 public NavigationDataSet getParsedData() {
      navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark().setCoordinates(buffer.toString().trim());
      return this.navigationDataSet; 
 } 

 // =========================================================== 
 // Methods 
 // =========================================================== 
 @Override 
 public void startDocument() throws SAXException { 
      this.navigationDataSet = new NavigationDataSet(); 
 } 

 @Override 
 public void endDocument() throws SAXException { 
      // Nothing to do
 } 

 /** Gets be called on opening tags like: 
  * <tag> 
  * Can provide attribute(s), when xml was like: 
  * <tag attribute="attributeValue">*/ 
 @Override 
 public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, 
           String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException { 
      if (localName.equals("kml")) { 
           this.in_kmltag = true;
      } else if (localName.equals("Placemark")) { 
           this.in_placemarktag = true; 
           navigationDataSet.setCurrentPlacemark(new Placemark());
      } else if (localName.equals("name")) { 
           this.in_nametag = true;
      } else if (localName.equals("description")) { 
          this.in_descriptiontag = true;
      } else if (localName.equals("GeometryCollection")) { 
          this.in_geometrycollectiontag = true;
      } else if (localName.equals("LineString")) { 
          this.in_linestringtag = true;              
      } else if (localName.equals("point")) { 
          this.in_pointtag = true;          
      } else if (localName.equals("coordinates")) {
          buffer = new StringBuffer();
          this.in_coordinatestag = true;                        
      }
 } 

 /** Gets be called on closing tags like: 
  * </tag> */ 
 @Override 
 public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName) 
           throws SAXException { 
       if (localName.equals("kml")) {
           this.in_kmltag = false; 
       } else if (localName.equals("Placemark")) { 
           this.in_placemarktag = false;

       if ("Route".equals(navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark().getTitle())) 
               navigationDataSet.setRoutePlacemark(navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark());
        else navigationDataSet.addCurrentPlacemark();

       } else if (localName.equals("name")) { 
           this.in_nametag = false;           
       } else if (localName.equals("description")) { 
           this.in_descriptiontag = false;
       } else if (localName.equals("GeometryCollection")) { 
           this.in_geometrycollectiontag = false;
       } else if (localName.equals("LineString")) { 
           this.in_linestringtag = false;              
       } else if (localName.equals("point")) { 
           this.in_pointtag = false;          
       } else if (localName.equals("coordinates")) { 
           this.in_coordinatestag = false;
       }
 } 

 /** Gets be called on the following structure: 
  * <tag>characters</tag> */ 
 @Override 
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) { 
    if(this.in_nametag){ 
        if (navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark()==null) navigationDataSet.setCurrentPlacemark(new Placemark());
        navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark().setTitle(new String(ch, start, length));            
    } else 
    if(this.in_descriptiontag){ 
        if (navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark()==null) navigationDataSet.setCurrentPlacemark(new Placemark());
        navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark().setDescription(new String(ch, start, length));          
    } else
    if(this.in_coordinatestag){        
        if (navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark()==null) navigationDataSet.setCurrentPlacemark(new Placemark());
        //navigationDataSet.getCurrentPlacemark().setCoordinates(new String(ch, start, length));
        buffer.append(ch, start, length);
    }
} 
}
```

and a simple placeMark bean:

```
package com.myapp.android.model.navigation;

public class Placemark {

String title;
String description;
String coordinates;
String address;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public String getCoordinates() {
    return coordinates;
}
public void setCoordinates(String coordinates) {
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}
public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

}
```

Finally the service class in my model that calls the calculation:

```
package com.myapp.android.model.navigation;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import com.myapp.android.myapp;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.util.Log;

public class MapService {

public static final int MODE_ANY = 0;
public static final int MODE_CAR = 1;
public static final int MODE_WALKING = 2;


public static String inputStreamToString (InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
    byte[] b = new byte[4096];
    for (int n; (n = in.read(b)) != -1;) {
        out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
    }
    return out.toString();
}


public static NavigationDataSet calculateRoute(Double startLat, Double startLng, Double targetLat, Double targetLng, int mode) {
    return calculateRoute(startLat + "," + startLng, targetLat + "," + targetLng, mode);
}

public static NavigationDataSet calculateRoute(String startCoords, String targetCoords, int mode) {
    String urlPedestrianMode = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + startCoords + "&daddr="
            + targetCoords + "&sll=" + startCoords + "&dirflg=w&hl=en&ie=UTF8&z=14&output=kml";

    Log.d(myapp.APP, "urlPedestrianMode: "+urlPedestrianMode);

    String urlCarMode = "http://maps.google.com/maps?" + "saddr=" + startCoords + "&daddr="
            + targetCoords + "&sll=" + startCoords + "&hl=en&ie=UTF8&z=14&output=kml";

    Log.d(myapp.APP, "urlCarMode: "+urlCarMode);

    NavigationDataSet navSet = null;
    // for mode_any: try pedestrian route calculation first, if it fails, fall back to car route
    if (mode==MODE_ANY||mode==MODE_WALKING) navSet = MapService.getNavigationDataSet(urlPedestrianMode);
    if (mode==MODE_ANY&&navSet==null||mode==MODE_CAR) navSet = MapService.getNavigationDataSet(urlCarMode);
    return navSet;
}

/**
 * Retrieve navigation data set from either remote URL or String
 * @param url
 * @return navigation set
 */
public static NavigationDataSet getNavigationDataSet(String url) {

    // urlString = "http://192.168.1.100:80/test.kml";
    Log.d(myapp.APP,"urlString -->> " + url);
    NavigationDataSet navigationDataSet = null;
    try
        {           
        final URL aUrl = new URL(url);
        final URLConnection conn = aUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15 * 1000);  // timeout for reading the google maps data: 15 secs
        conn.connect();

        /* Get a SAXParser from the SAXPArserFactory. */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser(); 

        /* Get the XMLReader of the SAXParser we created. */
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /* Create a new ContentHandler and apply it to the XML-Reader*/ 
        NavigationSaxHandler navSax2Handler = new NavigationSaxHandler(); 
        xr.setContentHandler(navSax2Handler); 

        /* Parse the xml-data from our URL. */ 
        xr.parse(new InputSource(aUrl.openStream()));

        /* Our NavigationSaxHandler now provides the parsed data to us. */ 
        navigationDataSet = navSax2Handler.getParsedData(); 

        /* Set the result to be displayed in our GUI. */ 
        Log.d(myapp.APP,"navigationDataSet: "+navigationDataSet.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Log.e(myapp.APP, "error with kml xml", e);
        navigationDataSet = null;
    }   

    return navigationDataSet;
}

}
```

Drawing:

```
/**
 * Does the actual drawing of the route, based on the geo points provided in the nav set
 *
 * @param navSet     Navigation set bean that holds the route information, incl. geo pos
 * @param color      Color in which to draw the lines
 * @param mMapView01 Map view to draw onto
 */
public void drawPath(NavigationDataSet navSet, int color, MapView mMapView01) {

    Log.d(myapp.APP, "map color before: " + color);        

    // color correction for dining, make it darker
    if (color == Color.parseColor("#add331")) color = Color.parseColor("#6C8715");
    Log.d(myapp.APP, "map color after: " + color);

    Collection overlaysToAddAgain = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iter = mMapView01.getOverlays().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        Object o = iter.next();
        Log.d(myapp.APP, "overlay type: " + o.getClass().getName());
        if (!RouteOverlay.class.getName().equals(o.getClass().getName())) {
            // mMapView01.getOverlays().remove(o);
            overlaysToAddAgain.add(o);
        }
    }
    mMapView01.getOverlays().clear();
    mMapView01.getOverlays().addAll(overlaysToAddAgain);

    String path = navSet.getRoutePlacemark().getCoordinates();
    Log.d(myapp.APP, "path=" + path);
    if (path != null && path.trim().length() > 0) {
        String[] pairs = path.trim().split(" ");

        Log.d(myapp.APP, "pairs.length=" + pairs.length);

        String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude lngLat[1]=latitude lngLat[2]=height

        Log.d(myapp.APP, "lnglat =" + lngLat + ", length: " + lngLat.length);

        if (lngLat.length<3) lngLat = pairs[1].split(","); // if first pair is not transferred completely, take seconds pair //TODO 

        try {
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
            mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(startGP, startGP, 1));
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;

            for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) // the last one would be crash
            {
                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");

                gp1 = gp2;

                if (lngLat.length >= 2 && gp1.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp1.getLongitudeE6() > 0
                        && gp2.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp2.getLongitudeE6() > 0) {

                    // for GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
                    gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));

                    if (gp2.getLatitudeE6() != 22200000) { 
                        mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(gp1, gp2, 2, color));
                        Log.d(myapp.APP, "draw:" + gp1.getLatitudeE6() + "/" + gp1.getLongitudeE6() + " TO " + gp2.getLatitudeE6() + "/" + gp2.getLongitudeE6());
                    }
                }
                // Log.d(myapp.APP,"pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
            //routeOverlays.add(new RouteOverlay(gp2,gp2, 3));
            mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(gp2, gp2, 3));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            Log.e(myapp.APP, "Cannot draw route.", e);
        }
    }
    // mMapView01.getOverlays().addAll(routeOverlays); // use the default color
    mMapView01.setEnabled(true);
}
```

This is the RouteOverlay class:

```
package com.myapp.android.activity.map.nav;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;

public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay { 

private GeoPoint gp1;
private GeoPoint gp2;
private int mRadius=6;
private int mode=0;
private int defaultColor;
private String text="";
private Bitmap img = null;

public RouteOverlay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode) { // GeoPoint is a int. (6E)
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.mode = mode;
    defaultColor = 999; // no defaultColor
}

public RouteOverlay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode, int defaultColor) {
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
}

public void setText(String t) {
    this.text = t;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) { 
    this.img = bitmap;
}

public int getMode() {
    return mode;
}

@Override
public boolean draw (Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if (shadow == false) {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
        // mode=1&#65306;start
        if(mode==1) {
            if(defaultColor==999)
            paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // Color.BLUE
            else
            paint.setColor(defaultColor);
            RectF oval=new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y - mRadius,
            point.x + mRadius, point.y + mRadius);
            // start point
            canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        }
        // mode=2&#65306;path
        else if(mode==2) {
            if(defaultColor==999)
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            else
            paint.setColor(defaultColor);
            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAlpha(defaultColor==Color.parseColor("#6C8715")?220:120);
            canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
        }
        /* mode=3&#65306;end */
        else if(mode==3) {
            /* the last path */

            if(defaultColor==999)
                paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);  // Color.GREEN
            else
                paint.setColor(defaultColor);

            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAlpha(defaultColor==Color.parseColor("#6C8715")?220:120);
            canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
            RectF oval=new RectF(point2.x - mRadius,point2.y - mRadius,
            point2.x + mRadius,point2.y + mRadius);
            /* end point */
            paint.setAlpha(255);
            canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        }
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}

}
```

Comment: Also this link might be interesting to you:
http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

Comment: Can you please provide a working example of the code that you have submiited in SO. Maybe a simple example of KML and SAxParsing.or some website from whee i can download it. I'm new to this and i prefer learning from working example. Thank You.

Comment: I don't have a standalone sample/apk of that. My sample is tightly integrated into a commercial app I've done. You can get any kml from the google maps web server, just calculate a route, then get the url of that route calculation from the browser, and add &output=kml to the url, that will give you the kml file.

Comment: I have put a print in the public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) method so I could check all the parsed values. Almost at the end the parsed file it says the complete distance between two points -->900&#160;m (about 11 mins)<br/>Map data &#169;2011 Google. 

Does someone know how to get this value? Do you need to create an extra tag in the end- and startElement method?

Comment: warning to future finders of this code, the characters() method is incorrect.  you should never assume that a single characters() method call will contain all the text content for a tag.

Comment: Thanks dude.  [Driving Direction](http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html) is very good.

Comment: Dear Mathias, Can you tell me why in RouteOverlay the point and point2 are always same. My gp1 and gp2 tho close but are different

Comment: @MathiasLin This way is still good enough?. I mean, with gmaps v2 I can't use the old Mapview class.

Comment: Can anyone create a simple project that uses kml so we can see how to work with it?

Comment: Recently <stylemap> is introduced which allows me to customize the tap on the path to see more details.

Answer (score 13):

Thank Mathias Lin, tested and it works!

In addition, sample implementation of Mathias's method in activity can be as follows.

```
public class DirectionMapActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.directionmap);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        String locationProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
        Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);

        StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
        urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
        urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
        urlString.append( Double.toString(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude() ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude() ));
        urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest[0]/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append(",");
        urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest[1]/1.0E6 ));
        urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");

        try{
            // setup the url
            URL url = new URL(urlString.toString());
            // create the factory
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            // create a parser
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            // create the reader (scanner)
            XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();
            // instantiate our handler
            NavigationSaxHandler navSaxHandler = new NavigationSaxHandler();
            // assign our handler
            xmlreader.setContentHandler(navSaxHandler);
            // get our data via the url class
            InputSource is = new InputSource(url.openStream());
            // perform the synchronous parse           
            xmlreader.parse(is);
            // get the results - should be a fully populated RSSFeed instance, or null on error
            NavigationDataSet ds = navSaxHandler.getParsedData();

            // draw path
            drawPath(ds, Color.parseColor("#add331"), mapView );

            // find boundary by using itemized overlay
            GeoPoint destPoint = new GeoPoint(dest[0],dest[1]);
            GeoPoint currentPoint = new GeoPoint( new Double(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude()*1E6).intValue()
                                                ,new Double(lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()*1E6).intValue() );

            Drawable dot = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pixel);
            MapItemizedOverlay bgItemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(dot,this);
            OverlayItem currentPixel = new OverlayItem(destPoint, null, null );
            OverlayItem destPixel = new OverlayItem(currentPoint, null, null );
            bgItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(currentPixel);
            bgItemizedOverlay.addOverlay(destPixel);

            // center and zoom in the map
            MapController mc = mapView.getController();
            mc.zoomToSpan(bgItemizedOverlay.getLatSpanE6()*2,bgItemizedOverlay.getLonSpanE6()*2);
            mc.animateTo(new GeoPoint(
                    (currentPoint.getLatitudeE6() + destPoint.getLatitudeE6()) / 2
                    , (currentPoint.getLongitudeE6() + destPoint.getLongitudeE6()) / 2));

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d("DirectionMap","Exception parsing kml.");
        }

    }
    // and the rest of the methods in activity, e.g. drawPath() etc...
```

MapItemizedOverlay.java

```
public class MapItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay{
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    private Context mContext;

    public MapItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
          super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
          mContext = context;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
      return mOverlays.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi alvinsj, is that possible to make a working project public, which perform the function above? Many thanks.

Answer (score 8):

There is now a beta available of [Google Maps KML Importing Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/kml).

It is part of the [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils). As documented it allows loading KML files from streams

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());
```

or local resources

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.kmlFile, getApplicationContext());
```

After you have created a KmlLayer, call addLayerToMap() to add the imported data onto the map.

```
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

Answer (score 4):

Mathias Lin code working beautifully. However, you might want to consider changing this part inside drawPath method:

```
 if (lngLat.length >= 2 && gp1.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp1.getLongitudeE6() > 0
                    && gp2.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp2.getLongitudeE6() > 0) {
```

GeoPoint can be less than zero as well, I switch mine to:

```
     if (lngLat.length >= 2 && gp1.getLatitudeE6() != 0 && gp1.getLongitudeE6() != 0
                    && gp2.getLatitudeE6() != 0 && gp2.getLongitudeE6() != 0) {
```

Thank you :D