# Google Maps - MapView - draw a nice flight route between 2 points

Tags: android, google-maps

I wonder,
how can I draw a nice flight route between 2 points on a google map's
MapView?

look at this:
http://maps.forum.nu/gm_flight_path.html

this is exactly what I need.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at my reply to question

[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

and there especially into the RouteOverlay class / draw method. 
Since you only want to draw a simple straight line, you probably won't need the rest of the complexity there.

Comment: That's the thing - I don't want to draw a simple straight line. I need a nice arc-like line to pass the feel of an airliner route.

Comment: I see; above sample url only draws straight lines, that why I thought... anyway, how to draw a curved line - refer to http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/200x/2009/01/02/Android-Draw-a-Curved-Line

Comment: @Mathias Lin - +1, great article. +1 on the original answer also.