# Android draw a path on a mapView from a large amount of longitude/latitude points

Tags: android, gps, android-mapview

I am writing a application that needs to draw a "route" comprised of lots of GPS points (long+lat). The points are close together and don't follow roads, simply drawing a line between each point is ideal.

The current implementation I have is very slow as I am looping over all the GPS coordinates and creating a new Point and overlayitem in an itemized overlay. This takes around 20 seconds for it to load all of these points and draw them to the mapview. Is there a way in which I can construct a series of lines or point from the GPS coordinates and draw them onto the mapview?

Example of current implementation:

```
 for each set of long+lats // removed to simplify
    point= new GeoPoint(latitude,longitude);
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"","");
    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
 mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
 mMapController.setCenter(point);
```

Thanks in advance, hope I've explained it well enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check my reply with code sample here:

[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

This example parses a kml files (xml format as provided by Google Maps or Google Earth for route calculation) and draws the geo points onto the map. If you already have a list of geo points, you can just look at the drawPath() method; and adjust the way you pass the geo coords parameters to it (I encapsulated it into a simple bean that I named NavigationDataSet).

Comment: Thanks it took some modifying but I managed to get it working, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're doing because I'm not sure how itemizedOverlay is drawing between the points.  But I bet the primary problem is that you're using a bunch of OverlayItems when it'd be much faster to just skip that part entirely and override the itemizedOverlay's `draw()` method.  I've done this before and it works quite well for line drawing.  The basic pseudocode is:

```
create List of GeoPoints
add List to ItemizedOverlay
add a dummy marker to ItemizedOverlay (so that it knows to call `draw()`)
in ItemizedOverlay.draw(), use mapView.getProjection() to map the array of GeoPoints to x,y coords
use Canvas.drawLines() to draw a line between all your points
```

Since speed is a concern, make sure to create the Paint objects in the ItemizedOverlay's constructor; they can be reused as much as you want.

Also as a side note, it looks like you're using `addOverlay()` as demonstrated in [the Hello, MapView demo](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html).  The only problem with using that is that they call `populate()` each time you add an item; if you are adding a bunch of points, it's better to add a bunch of overlays at once then call `populate()` at the end.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't select both answers as correct, but this info was helpful to me too, thanks :)