# MapActivity route drawing performance

Tags: android, google-maps

My app displays a route that users are supposed to follow and it also tracks the users progress. I'm using info I got from stackoverflow [Drawing a line/path on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2176397/294431) to draw my route. This works great on my device (LG Optimus S, v2.2) if there are less than 500 points but when I have 504 points it won't even open. There is no exception being thrown and there is no useful info in the logcat. It runs in the emulator with 800 points but it is REALLY slow.

One workaround I could use is to just create a image with transparent background (suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666723/how-to-make-route-drawing-more-efficient/6667184#6667184)  but I'm also letting the user track their progress so they could eventually have more than 500 points.

I know this must be possible because I asked for the route between LA and NYC and Google maps was able to draw it without a noticeable performance hit.

Is there a more efficient way to draw a route on the map?

Comment: I used a route simplification algorithm to reduce the number of points

Comment: How did you do this but still have detail?

Comment: I have written [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710098/problem-with-large-number-of-markers-on-the-map/4825908#4825908)