# how to do sax xml parsing in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, saxparser, android-parser

I have done one program in android using `xml` parsing but there is an error please solve this problem and explain how to use the `xml` parsing in android:

```
String response = rc.getResponse();
Log.e("Response ", response);

SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
LoginHandler myLoginHandler = new LoginHandler();

xr.parse(retrieveInputStream( response));
xr.parse(new InputSource(rc.openStream()));
```

Comment: Please post the error log if you're getting an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post and my reply: 
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

The second code snippet of the NavigationSaxHandler gives you an example how to use the sax parser.