# Is it possible to get a route demo for a prepared route in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am able to calculate route between two locations. Is it possible to show a route demo for the prepared route and show a car or some arrow travelling the route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This two links can help you out

- [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)
- http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

Comment: hey this much part i have already completed but now i want an actual demo of the route