# direction between two places in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

i am new in android 
and i want to make an application which display root between two places.
it is possible to display path in built in google map.
please help me to solve this.
thanx in advace

Comment: Will you want to create custom straight line between two places in Google map without using googleMapApi?

Answer (score 0):

The route between 2 places is shared by google through the directions() function. It is a method of the google maps api. Just read the manual.