# Android route between two locations on google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, routes

For my project i need to draw a path between two points on google maps. However i think the Google's KML file is not avaliable to all countries. I am from Turkey and Google Maps Api tells that driving directions are not avaliable for Turkey. In this case cant I reach the KML file and the intermediate coordinates between source and destination? What can I do in order to display a route? Should I define my own KML file?

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Driving directions are not available for Turkey. But when I paste this link

> http://maps.google.com/?q=from+Istanbul,Turkey+to+Ankara,Turkey&output=kml
>    to my browser it generates a kml file and automatically downloaded to your pc. Then you can add it into your project under res/raw folder and parse the elements.