# What is the use of KML in Google Maps, and how can I get them?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw routes between two points (lat and long) or two places. How can I get them from Google and is it possible to get my own address (home address) from Google and route maps of my desired locations. How can I  achieve this using KML file or the other way?

What are these KML files, are they necessary from me to get my route map? Can I get the route maps from Google?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I want to draw routes between two points (lat and long) or two places

you can draw route without using of KML file also. you can draw routs between to GEO point by using google map parameter. Here is the link for this:

http://mapki.com/wiki/Google_Map_Parameters

You can choose walking or driving direction also.

> 2. what are these KML files, are they necessary from me to get my route map? Can I get the route maps from Google?

KML file contains fix set of lat-long. So we can so the route between these lat-long. Here is a link how to draw route using KML
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)