# google map directons

Tags: android

i am using following code to point the marker on the map. please guide how can i draw the direction line from my current location to this point from the code . Like line pointing from source destination

```
String loc ="";
        String city ="s";
         String address = loc +  city 
         + ";
     String cleanAddress = address.replace(",", "");
     cleanAddress = cleanAddress.replace(' ', '+');

     try {
         Intent geoIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", android.net.Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="
             + cleanAddress));

         startActivity(geoIntent);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link, it is a tutorial about that.

http://csie-tw.blogspot.com/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html

Also, in this thread you can find more info:

[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)