# Displaying rout between two points in GMap, in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I want to display the rout in google map, between two points(Latitudes and longitudes), and I am able to draw straight line between these points, now I want to display rout.
Please guide me or suggest some link.

Answer (score 0):

http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START&daddr=DESTINATION&output=kml

Connect the coordinates and draw some lines to show your route.

Comment: You have a lot of coordinates in the .kml (can be used as if it was .xml) file. Draw a line between the first and the second location, then from 2nd to 3rd, from 3rd to 4th and on..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723

should help