# android google maps import are not recognized

Tags: android, google-maps

i tried to run the project which i found on this link

http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html

i tried to run it on android-sdk_r13-windows . i resolved class path error but still there are some error which i am unable to resolve like

```
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayController
import com.google.googlenav.DrivingDirection
import com.google.googlenav.map.MapPoint
```

these import are not recognized by compiler . i used android Google API 2.1 and also i have this entry in my manifest file.

```
<uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

any help on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `com.google.googlenav` package is really old and outdated, it was in the SDK0.9 very very long time ago. If you want to do route calculation, you need to use the Google Maps Web API, not the native API. You can combine both native MapView and it's api (for map display) together with Google Maps Web API (for route calculation) though.

How to calculate and draw a route, see my reply (first one in the list) of thread [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)