# Can I always keep some static Markers in Android Map?

Tags: android, dictionary, marker, itemizedoverlay

I'm a newbie into Android programming... Here's what I'm trying to do for a small academic project:

- A google map displayed on screen: **Done**
- Get user's current location and show on the map: **Done**
- We've a list of Latitudes and Longitudes coming from a webservice, which forms a pre-defined path. I need to display an always-shown path on the map with static markers as per the list of Lat-Longs given. **How?**

I tried various ways, and searched various places, but couldn't find a satisfactory code or tutorial that has achieved the same. Can someone please point me to an appropriate resource that I can use to get the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and check for static marker..................

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Maps/NooYawk

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/google-map-example-in-android-with-info.html

Comment: Thanks a Lot Divyesh. That's exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement [`Overlay`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) and draw the path in the `draw()` method.
Use this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723) to get an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Aromero... That's a big code, will take some time to understand, but I'm sure it'll be very useful for me!