# XML parsing with SAX: how to handle html as text within xml-tags

Tags: java, xml, sax, saxparser

I get an xml response from an external server.

Using some tutorials I got SAX-Parser working.

There is a small problem still remaining.

Within the response there is e.g. description tag containing html like this:

```
<description><p><strong>Title</strong></p>Description</description>
```

After parsing description field of my object contains only "<".

Is it possible to tell my parser to handle html as plain text?

Or maybe there are other possibilities to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you don't include your code, i have to imagine what you wrote.  a common bug in SAX handler implementations is not handling the fact that the element text may be returned in multiple characters() method calls.  you need to aggregate them all together until you get the endElement() event.

Comment: My code is pretty similar to code from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723 I try to include important parts

Comment: I did what you wrote and it works. Thank you. But should I do this aggregation for all tags? Or only if I think it can has special characters? Because I hadn't any problems with another tags. They were complete

Comment: you should always do it for every tag.  anything else is a bug waiting to happen (a sax parser is never required to give you all the text in one event).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from solution SAX problem, you might consider using Stax (javax.xml.stream) solution instead: it is as performance as SAX, but oftentime bit more convenient.
You can also force coalescing of textual content (XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING) to avoid problems like you are encountering with SAX.

Comment: I must see if this library is also available for android. Somehow is json parsing much funnier than xml parsing

Comment: Right -- I am pretty sure Woodstox is available; android does not include stax parser in its dev kit. And I fully agree wrt JSON, so much easier.