# Android - Turn by turn Navigation

Tags: android

how can I provide navigational turn-by-turn in the android application which I am making?
i didnt use google maps for this, i wanna build my own application which provide users with turn-by-turn navigation.

thx for helping me.

Comment: do you have a navigation provider already?

Comment: @DevYudh, Hi Did you implemented this? please help me I have to implement same like this.

Comment: @noundla yes i did, on my final project :D

Comment: @DevYudh Which maps did you used? Can have sample code for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google has the Directions API.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/

Just request the XML or JSON version and parse through it.  I used this in the past to draw a Point to Point path over the Google Maps view.  It worked fairly well and was fairly trivial.

Look at the XML output,  http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/#XML

Although what I used was the Coordinate information, it should be fairly trivial to parse the html_instructions to do what you want to do.

Here is a link to a past discussion where you can find code that does part of what you want:
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

You want to look for the answer from Alvinsj, DirectionMapActivity class.

Enjoy!

Comment: can you provide me some code to read the xml or json file which we got from google direction API ?

Comment: See the link that I added to the original post.  The code I mentioned was based on the code in that post.

Comment: http://code.google.com/intl/id-ID/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html#ParsinXML

thanks mate