# path tracing program in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, android-ndk

i want the source code for path tracking program in android.
i see the code in 
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)
public void drawPath(NavigationDataSet navSet, int color, MapView mMapView01) {

```
Log.d(myapp.APP, "map color before: " + color);        

// color correction for dining, make it darker
if (color == Color.parseColor("#add331")) color = Color.parseColor("#6C8715");
Log.d(myapp.APP, "map color after: " + color);

Collection overlaysToAddAgain = new ArrayList();
for (Iterator iter = mMapView01.getOverlays().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    Object o = iter.next();
    Log.d(myapp.APP, "overlay type: " + o.getClass().getName());
    if (!RouteOverlay.class.getName().equals(o.getClass().getName())) {
        // mMapView01.getOverlays().remove(o);
        overlaysToAddAgain.add(o);
    }
}
mMapView01.getOverlays().clear();
mMapView01.getOverlays().addAll(overlaysToAddAgain);

String path = navSet.getRoutePlacemark().getCoordinates();
Log.d(myapp.APP, "path=" + path);
if (path != null && path.trim().length() > 0) {
    String[] pairs = path.trim().split(" ");

    Log.d(myapp.APP, "pairs.length=" + pairs.length);

    String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude lngLat[1]=latitude lngLat[2]=height

    Log.d(myapp.APP, "lnglat =" + lngLat + ", length: " + lngLat.length);

    if (lngLat.length<3) lngLat = pairs[1].split(","); // if first pair is not transferred completely, take seconds pair //TODO 

    try {
        GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));
        mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(startGP, startGP, 1));
        GeoPoint gp1;
        GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;

        for (int i = 1; i < pairs.length; i++) // the last one would be crash
        {
            lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");

            gp1 = gp2;

            if (lngLat.length >= 2 && gp1.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp1.getLongitudeE6() > 0
                    && gp2.getLatitudeE6() > 0 && gp2.getLongitudeE6() > 0) {

                // for GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
                gp2 = new GeoPoint((int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1]) * 1E6), (int) (Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0]) * 1E6));

                if (gp2.getLatitudeE6() != 22200000) { 
                    mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(gp1, gp2, 2, color));
                    Log.d(myapp.APP, "draw:" + gp1.getLatitudeE6() + "/" + gp1.getLongitudeE6() + " TO " + gp2.getLatitudeE6() + "/" + gp2.getLongitudeE6());
                }
            }
            // Log.d(myapp.APP,"pair:" + pairs[i]);
        }
        //routeOverlays.add(new RouteOverlay(gp2,gp2, 3));
        mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new RouteOverlay(gp2, gp2, 3));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        Log.e(myapp.APP, "Cannot draw route.", e);
    }
}
// mMapView01.getOverlays().addAll(routeOverlays); // use the default color
mMapView01.setEnabled(true);
```

}
 but i am unable to execute the code.
if you donot mind can any once give the entire source code .

thanks.

Comment: android.app.ActionBar is not resolved.

Comment: listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_INSECURE, MY_UUID_INSECURE) this method is undefined .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two classes HomeActivity and MyOverlay to draw path in google map 
here is HomeActivity :

```
MapView mapView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.e("Home", " activity created");
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    double src_lat = 28.011022; // the testing source  28.011022,73.323802
    double src_long = 73.323802;
    double dest_lat = 28.008389; // the testing destination   28.008389,73.33599
    double dest_long = 73.33599;

    Log.e("Home ", " Strting drawing path");
    GeoPoint srcGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (src_lat * 1E6),
            (int) (src_long * 1E6));
    GeoPoint destGeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int) (dest_lat * 1E6),
            (int) (dest_long * 1E6));
    Log.e("Home ", " Strting drawing path");

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.darkgreen_marker);
    mapView.getOverlays();
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(srcGeoPoint, "Hello!", "This is your position");
    overLay marker_overlay=new overLay(drawable);
    marker_overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(marker_overlay);
    overlayitem = new OverlayItem(destGeoPoint, "Theater Big ", "Go to this ");
    marker_overlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(marker_overlay);
    //mapView.getOverlays().add(new overLay(null, destGeoPoint));

    DrawPath(srcGeoPoint, destGeoPoint, Color.GREEN, mapView);      
    mapView.getController().animateTo(srcGeoPoint);
    mapView.getController().setZoom(15);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;
}

private void DrawPath(GeoPoint src,GeoPoint dest, int color, MapView mMapView01)
{
    // connect to map web service
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en");
    urlString.append("&saddr=");//from
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)src.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&daddr=");//to
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLatitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append( Double.toString((double)dest.getLongitudeE6()/1.0E6 ));
    urlString.append("&ie=UTF8&0&om=0&output=kml");
    Log.e("Draw path  ","URL="+urlString.toString());
    // get the kml (XML) doc. And parse it to get the coordinates(direction route).
    Document doc = null;

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection= null;
    URL url = null;
    try
    {
        url = new URL(urlString.toString());
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.connect();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        Log.e(" Home ", " response"+doc.toString());
        if(doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").getLength()>0)
        {
            //String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeName();
            String path = doc.getElementsByTagName("GeometryCollection").item(0).getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getFirstChild().getNodeValue() ;
            Log.d("draw path ","path="+ path);
            String [] pairs = path.split(" ");
            String[] lngLat = pairs[0].split(","); // lngLat[0]=longitude lngLat[1]=latitude lngLat[2]=height
            // src
            GeoPoint startGP = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
            mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(startGP,startGP,1));
            GeoPoint gp1;
            GeoPoint gp2 = startGP;
            for(int i=1;i<pairs.length;i++) // the last one would be crash
            {
                lngLat = pairs[i].split(",");
                gp1 = gp2;
                // watch out! For GeoPoint, first:latitude, second:longitude
                gp2 = new GeoPoint((int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[1])*1E6),(int)(Double.parseDouble(lngLat[0])*1E6));
                mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(gp1,gp2,2,color));
                Log.d("Draw path","pair:" + pairs[i]);
            }
            mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(dest,dest, 3)); // use the default color
        }
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SAXException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class overLay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{
    private List<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    GeoPoint gp1;
    Drawable marker;

    public overLay(Drawable marker) {
        super(marker);
        this.marker=marker;
    }

    public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay){
        mOverlays.add(overlay);
        Log.e(" Map Overlay __", " adding new item "+overlay);
        populate();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        Point point = new Point();
        for(int i=0;i<mOverlays.size();i++){
            OverlayItem g = getItem(i);
            gp1=g.getPoint();
            projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
              Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                        getResources(), R.drawable.marker_red);            
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, point.x-10, point.y-35, null);
        }
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTap(int index){
        /* GeoPonit p MapView mapView*/
        OverlayItem item = getItem(index);
        GeoPoint gp=item.getPoint();
        String msg=item.getSnippet();

        mapView.getController().animateTo(gp);
        Log.e("-- map view --", " marker clicked "+gp);

        LayoutInflater infalter=getLayoutInflater();
        final LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)infalter.inflate(R.layout.popup_baloon_layout, null);  
        table.setWillNotDraw(false);
        final MapView.LayoutParams lp2 = new MapView.LayoutParams(
                150,100,gp,-15,-10,MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER);  
        TextView addrs=(TextView)table.findViewById(R.id.address);
        addrs.setText(msg);
        ImageView call_img=(ImageView)table.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        call_img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("__ Home __", " making call to 12345");
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                mapView.removeView(table);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("12345")));
                HomeActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        table.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mapView.removeView(table);
                //table=null;
            }
        });

        mapView.addView(table,lp2);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        Log.e("Map Overlay __", " creating overlay item "+i);
        return mOverlays.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        Log.e("Map Overlay __", " getting overlay size ");
        return mOverlays.size();
    }

}
```

and MyOverLay class :

```
public class MyOverLay extends Overlay{
private GeoPoint gp1;
private GeoPoint gp2;
//private int mRadius=6;
private int mode=0;
private int defaultColor;
//private String text="";
//private Bitmap img = null;
private Context context;

public MyOverLay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode,Context context){// GeoPoint is a int. (6E)
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.mode = mode;
    defaultColor = 999; // no defaultColor
    this.context=context;
}

public MyOverLay(GeoPoint gp1,GeoPoint gp2,int mode, int defaultColor,Context context){
    this.gp1 = gp1;
    this.gp2 = gp2;
    this.mode = mode;
    this.defaultColor = defaultColor;
    this.context=context;
}

/*public void setText(String t){
    this.text = t;
}

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    this.img = bitmap;
}*/

public int getMode(){
    return mode;
}

@Override
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when){
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
    if (shadow == false){
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Point point = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
        // mode=1&#65306;start
        if(mode==1){
            if(defaultColor==999)
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            else
            paint.setColor(defaultColor);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.getResources(), R.drawable.marker_red);            
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, point.x-10, point.y-35, null);

            /*RectF oval=new RectF(point.x - mRadius, point.y - mRadius,
            point.x + mRadius, point.y + mRadius);*/
            // start point
            //canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);
        }
        // mode=2&#65306;path
        else if(mode==2){
            if(defaultColor==999)
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            else
            paint.setColor(defaultColor);
            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAlpha(120);
            canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
        }
        /* mode=3&#65306;end */
        else if(mode==3){
        /* the last path */

            if(defaultColor==999)
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            else
            paint.setColor(defaultColor);
            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);
            paint.setAlpha(120);
            canvas.drawLine(point.x, point.y, point2.x,point2.y, paint);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    context.getResources(), R.drawable.marker_red);            
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, point.x-16, point.y-38, null);
            /*RectF oval=new RectF(point2.x - mRadius,point2.y - mRadius,
            point2.x + mRadius,point2.y + mRadius);
            paint.setAlpha(255);
            canvas.drawOval(oval, paint);*/
        }
    }
    return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
}

@Override
public boolean onTap(GeoPoint p, MapView mapView){

    return false;
}
```

}

These classes use kml to draw path between two locations.

Comment: my requirement is when ever the user start the application it saves the longitude and latitude for every 5 seconds . after reach the destination then the application draw the map by using the saved longitude and latitude. is it possible?  thanks advanced

Comment: @venkat Then you have to just modify the DrawPath() function in HomeActivity class,simply use `mMapView01.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(dest,dest, 3));` and delete rest of code from DrawPath()

Comment: i am new for the android. so that why if i try to execute the code in that site it gives me so many errors. if you donot mind give me the entire application then i will test in my system and then i modify it please understand my problem

Comment: I have downloaded this example long time ago and don't have link.. I can send you this entire example by mail