# How to draw an overlay using KML on our own app in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, kml, android-maps

I want to draw an overlay using .kml files, just look like this. But on my own app in MapActivity.
[31.kml, display district in Jakarta, Indonesia](http://bit.ly/LDfFhH)
or
[the example that I get from googling](http://bit.ly/LatEdV)

I'd already try this code, but it's just open google map app even that already give me a map with KML's overlay.

`final Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32264286/Unggahan/31.kml"));startActivity(myIntent);`

Is it possible? And how can I implement this? Does anybody can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
@AdityaSetyadi

Answer (score 0):

To draw the maps using KML, on option is to write the code to parse KML and draw the overlays.

The solution is present with this link

[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)