# Android + google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to know if it is possibile with  google maps API create a path with more point?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is example of loading points from KML file and drawing path..

[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with Overlays as explained in the [API-Doku](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).