# Best way to use a lot of Places of Interest on a Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a server with a lot of Places of Interest information. (long, lat, picture url, name, etc) 
About 100.000 items.

1. What is the best way to: load/download it into Android, and
2. what is the best way to show them on a Google Maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a big amount of Markers I suggest you give KML Layers a shot.

With Google Maps you can either have google render all markers for you, (default: [KMLLayers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#KMLLayers))
or you can rely on [GeoXML3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) for client side parsing.

The same applies to Android Google Maps. Layers can easily be added using this: [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)