# Unable to import kml linestring file to My Places in google maps

Tags: google-maps, import, kml

I can no longer import kml files into My Places in google maps, even files that have worked in the past.
I have even tried copying an example from [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file?rq=1)
but get the error "We could not finish uploading your file".

So I no longer think it is a kml syntax issue but a google maps bug - please help.

Comment: I confirm the problem here and this is not a file issue 'cause well working files are not working today.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.  I was using Firefox 19.0.2.  Just tried with IE8 and it worked fine.

Comment: I am using IE9. I get the same in Chrome, Firefox 19.0, etc

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what to do
I got the same error because my kml file exceeded 3MB

Here is what worked for me.

1. I imported the file (gpx or kml) into Google Earth on
   My computer
2. then I selected the imported file and clicked to save the file on my
   desktop. This caused Google Earth to "convert" my large file into
   a .kml file that had all points but was much smaller
3. finally that smaller file- created by Google Earth- easily and quickly
   uploaded to my Places