# Is it possible to open a kml file on Gmaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

i was wondering if it is possible to open a kml file from my app.
I have the google api 8 and i instantiate an object GoogleMap

```
GoogleMap = m_gmap
m_gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
m_gmap.getMyLocation();
...and so on.
```

supposing there's a way to open the file from my app, how can i toggle the new layers added by the kml?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

here is a link to an answer that might help you ,[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723)
but as far as I know kml format is not supported anymore by google responses, google supports JSON and XML.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i will not implement something like that :P