# Android: Fail to retrieving a tag value of the EWS response

Tags: android, xml-parsing, exchangewebservices, xmlpullparser

I am hitting my Exchange server using (EWS+Basic Authentication). I could authenticate and hit my services with these Request **GetItem (E-mail Message),SyncFolderItems and few other** and getting the response successfully. I could parse the SyncFolderItems response to get basic info abt the Mail Items (Like **Subject,To,From,HasAttachments etc**.). But when i hit the GetItem request i am receiving a response but i couldnt get the **Mail item Body (i.e, the Message).** Is it any tutorial to do this. I am using XMLPullParser..

The response might be look like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa566013%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) . Plz guide me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for ur valuable replies.. I found the data (values) that i stored from the saxparser is not complete. So only i couldnt get the html content properly in the webview.

i used the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723) as reference and used the string buffer to resolve this issue.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I've used [JWebServices for Exchange (Android version)](http://www.independentsoft.de/jwebservices) several times. It's not free but accomplished what I needed. You should try the API to see if they get correct Body to see if your application fails or body is empty.