# How to overlay kmz file on google maps using eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, kmz

Is there a way to overlay directly a kmz file on google maps using the map activity class on android?

Answer (score 0):

`MapActivity` class is deprecated. Consider using [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) if you are just starting.

> Is there a way to overlay directly a kmz file (...)?

Yes. As directly as decompressing and parsing the file. For parsing you may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109723/2183804 or just google "android kml parser". If you use API v2, ignore anything related to `MapView` and `MapActivity` from that answer.