# android kml import export using google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

i am developing location based application.I want to export given map to kml file and import kml file into android google map.Is there any way to implement kml in android?

Answer (score 2):

For KML implementation you can look into this so - [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

**Basic structure of KML file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
 <Placemark> 
 <name>My Simple Placemark</name> 
 <description>Your Description goes here</description> 
 <Point> 
 <coordinates> longitude, latitude, and optional altitude</coordinates> 
 </Point> 
 </Placemark> 
 </kml>
```

For Kml tutorial [visit here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut) and for KML path [visit here](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#paths)

To load KML file on android phone following code need to include:

```
final Intent myIntent = 
new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("http://myurl.com/kmlcode/path/KML_Sa
mples.kml")); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

or

```
final Intent myIntent = 
 new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
Uri.parse("file:///myurl.com/kmlcode/path/KML_Sa
mples.kml")); 
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Above code will open google map app and it will request the kml file from specified URL or file.

To implement the google API on android phone you have to add Google API library and set built target as Google API. You also need to set the permission in 
AndroidManifest.xml file like below:

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/
android" 
 package="com.example.package.name"> 
 ... 
 <application android:name="MyApplication" > 
 <uses-library 
android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 
 ... 
 </application> 
 ... 
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

</manifest>
```

To add MapView control you need to code the following in layout file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 

 android:id="@+id/mapview" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:clickable="true" 
 android:apiKey="Your Maps API Key goes here" 
/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry there currently is no method to export the KML from a given android map.  Once you display the kml on the Android Google Map API V2 there is no way to recover it.

Export
You have to design a method where you update your kml as you update your map or you update a class that keeps track of all your kml markers and kml points etc as you update your map so you can later serialize out the kml.

Import
There are a few examples out there but you pretty much have to roll your own display of kml.  Look for something on github maybe someone is generous.