# How to display (publicly available i.e. non-local) KML file on a Google Map (Android fragment)

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, kml

I am trying to find a way to display a KML layout over a Google Map in my Android application. The KML file itself is hosted on Google App Engine (publicly accessible). I have seen many posts regarding manually parsing locally-stored KML files, but it isn't clear to me if this is something you only have to do if you are trying to display a local KML file. However, I have not seen any evidence of a different straight-forward way to display publicly available KML files. Google's KML support for Google Maps Mobile (https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport#googlemapsformobile) seems to imply that displaying KML files directly in Google Maps is indeed supported.

Is there any way to display a publicly accessible (by public URL) KML layer file over a Google Map in Android without manually parsing the file???

Answer (score 0):

This should help you, in case you want to display a route between two points: http://blog.synyx.de/2010/06/routing-driving-directions-on-android-part-1-get-the-route/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem lately and the only solution I've seen was parsing the KML file. It's not that complicated, KML is kind of a XML file, you know the tags and you can parse it easily.

Google is trying to make it better and lately and they have built a new app for this. Look: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.m4b

Comment: All right, thank you for the reply! It seems that the best manual parser I have found is the one at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723

I have polygons in my KML file, but this parser setup does not seem to look for polygons. Do you know of one that does?