# How can I parse kml file from the assets folder?

Tags: android

I have Kml file which have some lat lngs but I don't know how to parse it in android?

I checked this link
[How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

but it's different. It is getting the data from the server in kml format. But I have kml file stored in assets.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: so you know how to create KML Object from text?

Comment: @PratikButani I don't know..

Answer (score 0):

Read KML:

```
public String loadKMLFromAsset() {

    String kmlData = null;
    try {

        InputStream is = getAssets().open("yourKMLFile");

        int size = is.available();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];

        is.read(buffer);

        is.close();

        kmlData = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");


    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return kmlData;

}
```