# How to load KML File in folder Assets with Xamarin Android

Tags: java, android, xamarin, kml

I put my file into the Assets directory and set the build action to "*AndroidAsset*"

Nevertheless, I can't access my KML file using the [parseKmlFile method](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/kml/KmlDocument.java)

I need to affect my Kml file to a Java.IO.File but the file I placed doesn't exist.

```
        Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File ("file:///android_asset/Content/maplayer.kml");
        Java.IO.File file2 = new Java.IO.File ("Content/maplayer.kml");
        Java.IO.File file3 = new Java.IO.File ("/Content/maplayer.kml");
        Java.IO.File file4 = new Java.IO.File ("maplayer.kml");

        if (file.Exists ())             
        Log.Debug ("File IO", file.ToString ());
        if (file2.Exists ())        
        Log.Debug ("File IO", file2.ToString ());
        if (file3.Exists ())        
        Log.Debug ("File IO", file3.ToString ());
        if (file4.Exists ())        
        Log.Debug ("File IO", file4.ToString ());
```

My file is located to : *Assets/Content/maplayer.kml*

I verified that asset is without **S** and that I have 3 "**/**"
So where is my Kml file located ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can do it like it was a Xml file, but see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23491352/how-can-i-parse-kml-file-from-the-assets-folder) helps you.

Comment: Second link did the job