# Display Google Shared Map Into Android App

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have searched this topic without good results.

I have created a map with personal markers into Google Maps account (shared map).

Now I want to display that map into an Android App with Google Maps API

It's that possible?

I want to do this so I can update markers of the map direclty from the web and the app always will be up to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is to get the kml file containing all the objects of your custom map layer.

1. Open your map (e.g. https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zbzKgwyzjU1k.kfNmxdgezpIg)
2. Change the link from **edit** to **kml** (note that you'll need to make the map public)
3. Result: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?mid=zbzKgwyzjU1k.kfNmxdgezpIg

Now that you have a link to your map with up to date information on the new items, you can fetch and parse it every time you start your app.

There are plenty of sources that tell you how you can parse xml files, kml is about the same.

Comment: so, this way, I'll have to include the new KML file into my project, every time I update my map?

Comment: @lauchaxxx When you update your map, the online KML is updated automatically, and once the user restarts his app, the parser will re-fetch all the data from that online KML and parse it into your map.

Comment: I found this post its old, I think is for an older version but your answer is correct, the way you suggested is the way to go.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723