# PolygonOptions addPolygon NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I try to open kml file on Google Maps :

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.community, getContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();
```

inside :

```
onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
```

but I am getting this exception :

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

> 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polygon
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addPolygon(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions)'
>   on a null object reference

Any help please ?

Thanks

Comment: Please check PolygonOptions object != null

Comment: There is no PolygonOptions object, I am just trying to parse a kml file with 2 simple code line :
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), R.raw.community, getContext());
layer.addLayerToMap();

Comment: Post polygon drawing code

Comment: @GeniDeveloper, maybe you are have missed some steps importing KML files to your map. Here is some guide by [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/kml#demo-app) and [How to draw a path on a map using kml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file/3109723#3109723) for your reference

Comment: I found the solution, I was putting the kml load before the map getting ready.

Answer (score 0):

Fragments in activities
Change super.onCreate (savedInstanceState) to super.onCreate (null).

Comment: Whilst it's good that you are providing an answer, but code snippets should always come with an explanation, thank you!