# In android create an activity with google map to show a route between two locations

Tags: android, google-maps

I have two location points in my variable and I want to show a map with  the route between these two locations.
I just want a Google map with a route between the locations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a path on a map using kml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109158/how-to-draw-a-path-on-a-map-using-kml-file)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this 
[Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary)

To add this library add dependency in gradle as

```
compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'
```

Sample code

```
    GoogleDirection.withServerKey("YOUR_SERVER_API_KEY")
            .from(new LatLng(37.7681994, -122.444538))
                .to(new LatLng(37.7749003,-122.4034934))
                .avoid(AvoidType.FERRIES)
                .avoid(AvoidType.HIGHWAYS)
                .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
            if(direction.isOK()) {
                // Do something
Snackbar.make(btnRequestDirection, "Success with status : " + direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = direction.getRouteList().get(0).getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            googleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));

        }

            } else {
                // Do something
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
            // Do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: onDirectionSuccess() will give the direction and rawBody but how i am gonna show in activity?

Comment: see updated code and please have a look at the sample given in link

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Google Maps Directions API in your console
2. you could transfer that code to a map listener EG.

   ```
   @Override
       public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
           GoogleDirectionConfiguration.getInstance().setLogEnabled(true);
             $key = getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key; 

           GoogleDirection.withServerKey($key))
               .from(mCurrLocationMarker.getPosition())
               .to(latLng)
               .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
               .transitMode(TransitMode.BUS)
               .unit(Unit.METRIC)
               .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {

                       Log.d("GoogleDirection", "Response Direction Status: " + direction.toString()+"\n"+rawBody);

                       if(direction.isOK()) {
                           // Do something
                           Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                           Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);
                           ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = leg.getDirectionPoint();
                           PolylineOptions polylineOptions = DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getApplication(), directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED);
                           mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                       } else {
                           // Do something
                       }
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
                       // Do something
                       Log.e("GoogleDirection", "Response Direction Status: " + t.getMessage()+"\n"+t.getCause());
                   }
               });
   }
   ```

Comment: forgive my poor code uploading skills. I am a new bee here.

Comment: replace `compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.4'` with `compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'` to enable logging. [link](http://www.akexorcist.com/2015/12/google-direction-library-for-android-en.html)